# Oracle ORDS middle-tier scalability, as it ties to OCPU allocation on Oracle Autonomous DB

Tags: oracle, oracle-ords, oracle-autonomous-db

I'm looking for any specific architecture information with regard to how the APEX ORDS middle-tier layer scales on an ADB implementation.  Specifically, as a factor of changing the OCPUs for the ADB, does that APEX ORDS middle-tier also scale as well?  Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation to the number of oCPUs on your Autonomous Database and the Oracle REST Data Services mid-tier deployments.

Each region has X ORDS nodes deployed, front-ended by a LoadBalancer.

Each of those X nodes will have a connection pool for each PDB, 100 connections each.

As demand increases in a region, the managed ORDS environment can quickly be increased by our DevOps team (either by button press or automation).

You can handle quite a few concurrent user requests if you have 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, even 1200 connections available.

If not, then you might consider:

1. making sure your SQL and PL/SQL are optimal for HTTPS, i.e. making it FAST
2. [deploy a customer-managed instance of ORDS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/22.2/ordig/installing-and-configuring-customer-managed-ords-autonomous-database.html) on your own tenancy compute node - you setup ORDS and give it as many resources as you want. Of course at this point, you're managing your mid-tier, not us.